# How can I use RDFa with WordPress?

Tags: plugins

Drupal 7 [has support](http://drupal.org/node/574624) for the semantic web (RDF/RDFa). Is there a plugin or similar plans for WordPress?

Comment: Are you really needing this for something or it's just asking because it's cool sort of something?

Comment: Want to use it for rel tagging of data. Things like SKOS and Dublin Core, but many other vocabularies might be interesting.

Comment: Can you please add links to a description of "SKOS" and "Dublin Core" and - if available - example code how this should look like in the end?

Comment: SKOS is experimental, but I would assume something that expose the taxonomy in this format and enables editing of it. http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/
For DublinCore I will investigate http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-rdfa/

Comment: yes i installed the rdfa moduel at my site http://softwarebuzzer.com but its not suit iwth the latest version of wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no plans to implement RDF into WordPress. RDFa on the other hand can be quite easily implemented by any theme or plugin author by simply adding the RDFa attributes to the generated markup.

Writing a plugin to expose WordPress' taxonomy as RDF wouldn't be hard and making it two-ways would probably not be that difficult either. I know of no plugins in existence that does this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/rdfa

Probably wouldn't be that hard to write a plugin for it. What's your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress can automatically generate an RDF feed

```
<?php bloginfo('rdf_url'); ?>
```